100% disk usage with no read/write, chkdsk /r freezing



specs





OS
Windows 10


mobo
asus prime b650-plus


cpu
Ryzen 5 7600X


ram
2*16 GB DDR5


video
RX 6650 XT


problem drive
M.2 kingston SNV2S2000G



Almost at my wits end but I figure it's better to ask here for a solution since all there other similar issue solutions didn't so hopefully if someone else encounters the same they can find it here if there is one.
While in use my M.2 drive has started suddenly going 100% active with no read or write happening, freezing anything using the drive.
Also in all cases when the drive is being problematic event viewer gets spammed with event id 129 from stornvme

Reset to device, \Device\RaidPort1, was issued.

Things I've tried:
Power setting is already high performance
Disabling antivirus does nothing
Physically removed and cleaned connector with methyl spirits, no sign of damage/burn on visual inspection.
S.M.A.R.T. ok, though takes a minute to select the drive in menu
CrystalDiskInfo result
Latest firmware and manufacturer software says ok.
UEFI self check pass on extended with controller and namespace test.
Chkdsk via command prompt unable to complete with /r, also graph has peaks instead of flat full line. Also had to force power off after chkdsk froze, would not enter shutdown after closing everything.
Chkdsk seems to pass /f and /scan fine by themselves, but when I run chkdsk /r by itself repeatedly it gets suck on step 4 at 3509 of 1205488.
chkdsk log

PS F:> chkdsk /f The type of the file system is NTFS. Cannot lock
current drive.
Chkdsk cannot run because the volume is in use by another process.
Chkdsk may run if this volume is dismounted first. ALL OPENED HANDLES
TO THIS VOLUME WOULD THEN BE INVALID. Would you like to force a
dismount on this volume? (Y/N) y Volume dismounted.  All opened
handles to this volume are now invalid. Volume label is M.2 Drive 1.
Stage 1: Examining basic file system structure ...   1205504 file
records processed. File verification completed.  Phase duration (File
record verification): 3.59 seconds.   726 large file records
processed.  Phase duration (Orphan file record recovery): 0.00
milliseconds.   0 bad file records processed.  Phase duration (Bad
file record checking): 0.14 milliseconds.
Stage 2: Examining file name linkage ...   394 reparse records
processed.   1477184 index entries processed. Index verification
completed.  Phase duration (Index verification): 11.16 seconds.   0
unindexed files scanned.  Phase duration (Orphan reconnection): 1.41
seconds.   0 unindexed files recovered to lost and found.  Phase
duration (Orphan recovery to lost and found): 3.40 milliseconds.   394
reparse records processed.  Phase duration (Reparse point and Object
ID verification): 3.20 milliseconds.
Stage 3: Examining security descriptors ... Security descriptor
verification completed.  Phase duration (Security descriptor
verification): 1.11 milliseconds.   135840 data files processed.
Phase duration (Data attribute verification): 0.15 milliseconds.
CHKDSK discovered free space marked as allocated in the master file
table (MFT) bitmap.
Windows has made corrections to the file system. No further action is
required.
1953497087 KB total disk space.  662130916 KB in 1068679 files.
309228 KB in 135842 indexes.
0 KB in bad sectors.    1331255 KB in use by the system.
65536 KB occupied by the log file. 1289725688 KB available on disk.
  4096 bytes in each allocation unit.  488374271 total allocation units on disk.  322431422 allocation units available on disk. Total

duration: 16.18 seconds (16183 ms). PS F:> chkdsk /r The type of the
file system is NTFS. Cannot lock current drive.
Chkdsk cannot run because the volume is in use by another process.
Chkdsk may run if this volume is dismounted first. ALL OPENED HANDLES
TO THIS VOLUME WOULD THEN BE INVALID. Would you like to force a
dismount on this volume? (Y/N) y Volume dismounted.  All opened
handles to this volume are now invalid. Volume label is M.2 Drive 1.
Stage 1: Examining basic file system structure ...   1205504 file
records processed. File verification completed.  Phase duration (File
record verification): 3.53 seconds.   726 large file records
processed.  Phase duration (Orphan file record recovery): 0.00
milliseconds.   0 bad file records processed.  Phase duration (Bad
file record checking): 0.43 milliseconds.
Stage 2: Examining file name linkage ...   394 reparse records
processed.   1477186 index entries processed. Index verification
completed.  Phase duration (Index verification): 10.98 seconds.   0
unindexed files scanned.  Phase duration (Orphan reconnection): 1.40
seconds.   0 unindexed files recovered to lost and found.  Phase
duration (Orphan recovery to lost and found): 3.37 milliseconds.   394
reparse records processed.  Phase duration (Reparse point and Object
ID verification): 3.04 milliseconds.
Stage 3: Examining security descriptors ... Security descriptor
verification completed.  Phase duration (Security descriptor
verification): 1.03 milliseconds.   135841 data files processed.
Phase duration (Data attribute verification): 0.20 milliseconds.
Stage 4: Looking for bad clusters in user file data ... Progress: 3509
of 1205488 done; Stage:  0%; Total:  0%; ETA:   1:07:39 .

Properties error check says error when in safe boot, but doesn't seem to fix anything and freezes in normal boot and requires forced shutdown.
Safe boot result
Normal Boot result
Any help would be appreciated, if you need me to perform addition diagnosis thats fine as well.
